# What's wrong with my VBScript code? (null) : Unspecified error message

Tags: vbscript

What's wrong with my VBScript code?

When it runs in cmd, after it browses for the file, "(null) : Unspecified error" happens

```
Function BrowseForFile()
    Dim shell 
    Dim file 
    Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    set file = shell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a file", &h4001& ,OpenAt)

    If Not file is Nothing Then
        BrowseForFile = " Title: " & file.title + " Path: " & file.self.path
    Else 
        WScript.Quit
    End If
End Function
```

And here is the code:

```
Dim Firstresponse
Dim Secondresponse
Dim path

Firstresponse = inputbox("ID")

if IsEmpty(Firstresponse) Then 
   'cancel button was pressed
    WScript.Quit
End If

Secondresponse = inputbox("File Dir")

if IsEmpty(Secondresponse) Then 
   'cancel button was pressed
   WScript.Quit
End if

set path=BrowseForFile()
If IsObject( path ) Then
    WScript.Echo "Object: ", path
else
    WScript.Echo "No object selected; Cancel clicked"
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though you are mixing testing for an object response and a string response.

The BrowseForFile function is going to return the string `" Title: " & file.title + " Path: " & file.self.path`but your code `set path=BrowseForFile()` is expecting the response from the function to be an object, not a string.

You can either do `path=BrowseForFile()` and handle the string response, or do

`set path=BrowseForFile()` and modify the function to return the object:

```
Function BrowseForFile()
    Dim shell 
    Dim file 
    Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    set file = shell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a file", &h4001& ,OpenAt)

    If Not file is Nothing Then
        set BrowseForFile = file
    Else 
        WScript.Quit
    End If
End Function
```

Here is an entire test file to try. I commented out the input boxes so this will just prompt for the folder selection and echo the string you construct.

```
Function BrowseForFile()
    Dim shell 
    Dim file 
    Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    set file = shell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a file", &h4001&, OpenAt)

    If Not file is Nothing Then
       BrowseForFile = " Title: " & file.title + " Path: " & file.self.path
    Else 
        WScript.Quit
    End If
End Function

Dim Firstresponse
Dim Secondresponse
Dim path

'Firstresponse = inputbox("ID")
'if IsEmpty(Firstresponse) Then 
   'cancel button was pressed
'    WScript.Quit
'End If

'Secondresponse = inputbox("File Dir")
'if IsEmpty(Secondresponse) Then 
   'cancel button was pressed
'   WScript.Quit
'End if

path=BrowseForFile()
If path <> "" Then
    WScript.Echo "Object: ", path
else
    WScript.Echo "No object selected; Cancel clicked"
End If
```

Test output

```
D:\>cscript test.vbs
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Object:   Title: Desktop Path: C:\Users\SCOTTSUPER\Desktop
```

Comment: I guess we all need to know what you want from the BrowseForFile function. Do you want the string you constructed or the object from the diaglog prompt?

Could you post the entire code as you have modified it?

Comment: I edited my answer with a full VBS code example that prints the string from BrowseForFolder.

Comment: Perhaps OpenAt should be set to something like 0 or 36 (System).

Comment: Thanks, this way it works. And I figured out why it didn't work before you commented out. The problem was I was not filling textbox, then "if IsEmpty(Secondresponse) Then WScript.Quit" was running.   I didn't know that Secondresponse returns the string which you fill the textbox with, and it doesn't have anything to do with the cancel button.

Answer (score 0):

When i run the code i get a different error

```
test.vbs(32, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: '[string: " Title: Desktop Path"]'
```

For that error you only need to change `set path=BrowseForFile()` to Change `path=BrowseForFile()` because its returning a string not an object.

Comment: I changed, but still there is an error vbs(7, 2) (null): Unspecified error

Comment: It just says this: (7, 2) (null): Unspecified error .. Do you know what does (7, 2) mean?

Comment: It means Line 7, Char 2

Comment: I see, but the line 7, should not have any problem! : if IsEmpty(Firstresponse) Then

Comment: Can you update you question to put all your code in one code block exactly as you have it in your vbs file.  I ask because the code you posted works when you fix the issue both me a @ScottEB pointed out, so i would assume there is a difference between what we see and whats in your script.  it might be small but important.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function BrowseForFile()
  Dim shell 
  Dim file 
  set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  set file = shell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a file", &h4001& ,OpenAt)

  If Not file is Nothing Then
    BrowseForFile = " Title: " & file.title + " Path: " & file.self.path
  Else 
    WScript.Quit
  End If
End Function


Dim Firstresponse
Dim Secondresponse
Dim path

Firstresponse = inputbox("ID")

if IsEmpty(Firstresponse) Then 
  'cancel button was pressed
  WScript.Quit
End If

Secondresponse = inputbox("File Dir")

if IsEmpty(Secondresponse) Then 
  'cancel button was pressed
  WScript.Quit
End if

path=BrowseForFile()
If IsObject( path ) Then
    WScript.Echo "Object: ", path
else
    WScript.Echo "No object selected; Cancel clicked"
End If
```

Comment: You should have just edited your question.  And you'll also want to change 'If IsObject( path ) Then' to 'If TypeName(path) = "String" Then'